# Vue component registration

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have imported the component
in the js file

```
import fmsSubUnitDetails from '../subunitDetails';

export default{
 components: {
    fmsSubUnitDetails
  },
}
```

in the index.vue file

`<fmsSubUnitDetails></fmsSubUnitDetails>`

but still getting error

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

I have tried changing path like adding or removing '/' in the import, it renders the component but as soon as I hard refresh, the component stops rendering again.

Comment: How do you use it in html?

Comment: Try kebab format or first letter uppercase

Comment: Usually when you have this kind of an error it says which component is not registered. In your case there is no name. That’s weird

Comment: it shows the same name i.e. fmsSubUnitDetails, during posting the question it got omitted

Comment: tried kebab case and first letter uppercase but did not work

Comment: How are you exporting the component from `subunitDetails.vue`? In case you do a named export instead of a default export, you might have to destructure the import result.

Comment: for exporting 

export default {
name: 'SubUnitDetails',
data() {
return {
*properties*
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Is it a recursive component? If so, I think you need to use the same name you defined on the component (or the kebab version of it)

```js
export default { 
    name: 'SubUnitDetails', 
    data() { 
        return { properties };
    }
}
```

```js
import SubUnitDetails from '../subunitDetails';

export default {
    components: { SubUnitDetails },
}
```

```html
<SubUnitDetails></SubUnitDetails >
```